# NSDateFormatter dateFromString always returns (null)

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdateformatter

I am trying to use NSDateFormatter's dateFromString but it always returns (null)

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
NSLog(@"%@", [dateFormatter dateFromString:[[myArray objectAtIndex:x] objectForKey:@"finish"]]);
```

The date in question is this: `2017-05-15 5:00:00 PM`

But it always returns (null)

I have tried adding these:

```
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]];
[dateFormatter setFormatterBehavior:NSDateFormatterBehaviorDefault];
```

But still returns null.

Please Help!

Comment: Please compare the date string with the date format. It clearly doesn't match. There is no equivalent of hours, minutes, seconds and AM/PM

Comment: Unrelated but use modern Objective-C syntax: `myArray[x][@"finish"]` instead of `[[myArray objectAtIndex:x] objectForKey:@"finish"]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You dateFormat is wrong. You need to use:

```
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd h:mm:ss a"];
```

Comment: Actually it's `h:mm:ss`

Comment: It would be very rare to combine `H` (24-hour) and `a`

Comment: @vadian true xD my bad.